# Visual Studio Class Diagram Viewer stand alone

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml, class-diagram

Visual Studio Makes Class diagrams and if we open it in text editor program it is a simple `XML`. Surely we can generate that on runtime. But the problem is although you have visual studio to see the `Class Diagram` Generated but what solution is there if we want to deploy application where there is no `Visual Studio` Installed?

1. Is there any possibility or available plugin or library that can generate Class diagram or UML diagram from XML?
2. Can we somehow use Visual Studio Class Diagram to view it on runtime?
3. Not Sure but what if we generate xml on Back end and then if possible create Image (png or gif) using some builtin plugin and display that? (I am really not sure about this idea :()

I have seen [NClass](http://nclass.sourceforge.net/) It is very good but a bit complex and it is not developed through XML.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts/

Comment: You are asking for standalone viewer for Visual Studio cd file ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula yes i am asking for stand alone viewer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use PowerToys for Class Designer (http://modeling.codeplex.com). It improves the Class Designer and allows you to export diagrams to HTML. This way is easy to distribute to any machine.

As an alternative, you can take a different path with reflection, in this case you don't need the visual studio class diagram; the diagrams are generated by inspecting the requested types. I suggest to read the articles by Sacha Barber (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17823/100-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207280/200-Reflective-Class-Diagram-Creation-Tool). Maybe you can customize his application.

Comment: If it exports to html, then it is providing a standalone. You can open the html files from everywhere with any browser. Is is not what you are asking with: 2.Can we somehow use Visual Studio Class Diagram to view it on runtime?

Comment: I I have tried you it generates png and shows in html. for that you need to have visual studio. What if i want to distrubute a thing say that would generate custom or variable diagrams then I need to find out solution

Comment: Added an alternative solution, hope it is closer to your needs

Comment: need same thing for visual studio 2013

Answer (score 5):

In Visual Studio Enterprise 2017:

1. Quit Visual Studio if it is running
2. Start Visual Studio Installer
3. Click dropdown list "More" and select "Modify"
4. In section "Code tools", check the option for "Class Designer"
5. Click button:  Modify

Result:  now the Class Diagram should load from Solution Explorer as UML.

Comment: Location in the 2019 installer was a bit different - find Modify, then click the tab at the top for Individual Components and scroll down the list to find Class Designer.